# Question on John 4:13-14 - How do we drink of the water from Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christian-living, gospel-of-john

I've been struggling with this passage for a while:

> Jesus said to her, “Everyone who drinks of this water will be thirsty again, but whoever drinks of the water that I will give him will never be thirsty again. The water that I will give him will become in him a spring of water welling up to eternal life.” 
>   [John 4:13-14 (ESV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%204:13-14&version=ESV)

**How does one drink of the water from Jesus?**

Comment: Please don't ask just for thoughts and opinions, we are learning that leads to low quality answers. Instead ask specifically what official teachings are on a matter.

Comment: [What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690)

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I took out the last line. Is this just a bad question in general? I was dying to ask it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Calvin's [commentary](http://www.sacred-texts.com/chr/calvin/cc34/cc34009.htm) on this passage affirms that "water" means the Spirit:

> Though the name *Water* is borrowed from the present occurrence, and applied to *the Spirit*, yet this metaphor is very frequent in Scripture, and rests on the best grounds. For we are like a dry and barren soil; there is no sap and no rigour in us, until the Lord water us by his Spirit. In another passage, the Spirit is likewise called *clean water*, (Heb 10:22,) but in a different sense; namely, because he washes and cleanses us from the pollutions with which we are entirely covered. But in this and similar passages, the subject treated of is the secret energy by which he restores life in us, and maintains and brings it to perfection.
>
> There are some who explain this as referring to the doctrine of the Gospel, to which I own that this appellation is fully applicable; but I think that Christ includes here the whole grace of our renewal; for we know that he was sent for the purpose of bringing to us a new life. In my opinion, therefore, he intended to contrast *water* with that destitution of all blessings under which mankind groan and labor. Again, *living water* is not so called from its effect, as *life-giving*, but the allusion is to different kinds of waters. It is called *living*, because it flows from a *living* fountain.

He finds that the reference to the spring or fountain has a particular significance:

> For he does not say that, from the very first day, we drink so as to be fully satisfied, but only means that the Holy Spirit is a continually flowing fountain; and that, therefore, there is no danger that they who have been renewed by spiritual grace shall be dried up. And, therefore, although we thirst throughout our whole life, yet it is certain that we have not received the Holy Spirit for a single day, or for any short period, but as a perennial fountain, which will never fail us. Thus believers thirst, and keenly thirst, throughout their whole life; and yet they have abundance of quickening moisture; for however small may have been the measure of grace which they have received, it gives them perpetual vigor, so that they are never entirely dry. When, therefore, he says that they shall be satisfied, he contrasts not with *Desire* but only with *Drought*.
>
> *Shall be a fountain of water springing up into eternal life.* These words express still more clearly the preceding statement; for they denote a continual watering, which maintains in them a heavenly eternity during this mortal and perishing life. The grace of Christ, therefore, does not flow to us for a short time, but overflows into a blessed immortality; for it does not cease to flow until the incorruptible life which it commences be brought to perfection.

The final paragraph shows the relevance of this passage to Calvinist ideas of irresistible grace and perseverance of the saints.

To me, this text brings to mind Matthew 20:20-23 and Mark 10:35-40, where Jesus asks his disciples "Can you drink the cup that I am to drink?". This question has been variously interpreted as referring to:

1. Martyrdom
2. General troubles and pains of life, not necessarily martyrdom
3. Baptism
4. The Eucharist
5. Receiving the Holy Spirit
6. Living a Christ-like life

It may not be possible or desirable to separate these meanings. Calvin's commentary is happy to assign multiple interpretations to the cup, since they are all bound up in the same idea.

Comment: Calvin is often a surprisingly beautiful writer, for all that he has such a severe reputation.

Answer (score 2):

John records many stories where Jesus is talking about something physical with spiritual undertones.  Jesus calls Himself the Bread of Life, the Good Shepherd, and the Gate for the sheep.

This really speaks to the fact that mankind is not purely physical, but are also spiritual beings.

We can identify with physical hunger for physical bread.  Jesus indicates that there is a spiritual hunger and that He Himself is the only thing that can satisfy that as the Bread of Life.

In this passage, Jesus identifies that there is a physical thirst with which all of us can identify.  He uses that to show the woman at the well that her own needs were not merely physical.  She had a spiritual thirst that could only be satisfied by spiritual water, and Jesus was the only source of such water.

There is a hunger that food cannot satisfy.  There is a thirst that water cannot quench.  There is a longing that nothing in this world can satisfy.  The hunger, the thirst, and the longing are not for physical things, but are for spiritual fulfillment which is found in God alone.

Comment: Thank you Narnian - your answer is insightful as well! :)